# How to specify non-default audio stream to MPlayer?

Tags: sound, video, video-player, mplayer

I have an AVI with two audio streams inside. How to play it with MPlayer using the 2nd non-default audio stream?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To find the audio track ID of the video that you want to play, use this:

```
mplayer -vo null -ao null -frames 0 -v <filename> | grep aid
```

To play the file using the audio track required, use the track ID that is found with the previous command and use it in the following one:

```
mplayer -aid <track_ID> <filename>
```

Source for this information - [FAQ at MPlayerhq.hu](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/faq.html#id2744203)

**Example:**

```
nits@nits-workstation:$ mplayer -vo null -ao null -frames 0 -v Blood\ \ 18\ Dual\ -\ Moon\ Over\ Ekaterinburg.mkv | grep aid
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.
[mkv] Track ID 2: audio (A_AAC), -aid 0, -alang und
[mkv] Track ID 3: audio (A_AAC), -aid 1, -alang und
FAAD: compressed input bitrate missing, assuming 128kbit/s!

##To play with Audio Track ID 3## 
nits@nits-workstation:$ mplayer -aid 1 Blood\ \ 18\ Dual\ -\ Moon\ Over\ Ekaterinburg.mkv 

##To play with Audio Track ID 2## 
nits@nits-workstation:$ mplayer -aid 0 Blood\ \ 18\ Dual\ -\ Moon\ Over\ Ekaterinburg.mkv
```